# How to create an xml file type database backend in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have an assignment to create a project in Visual Studio where a Webservice api can be called on a books.xml file. The front end is a web page that can add, remove or change books.

I was going trough [Tutorial: Create a web API with ASP.NET Core MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) when I´m starting to learn about Visual Studio and web api. My question is about this tutorial since it uses an in memory databas. Is is possible to instead use an XML file as databas or does it not even comply here?

Any ides would be create on how I should start with this.

I come from Java, Android and have some Visual Studio knowledge but not for backend apis

Answer (score 0):

You can use xml file for a small application not for an enterprise application. For a relational database you should prefer SQL . 
But for your project you can load xml file , add, update etc and apply some linq queries to extract data. for further CRUD methods of xml file you can see [this](http://www.worldbestlearningcenter.com/index_files/csharp-read-add-edit-remove-xml-linq.htm)
link.
Creation

```
new XDocument(
new XElement("root", 
    new XElement("someNode", "someValue")    
)).Save("conctacts.xml");
```

Loading of XML File
    var xml = XDocument.Load(@"C:\contacts.xml");

```
   // Query the data and write out a subset of contacts
        var query = from c in xml.Root.Descendants("contact")
        where (int)c.Attribute("id") < 4
        select c.Element("firstName").Value + " " +
               c.Element("lastName").Value;


        foreach (string name in query)
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Contact's Full Name: {0}", name);
        }
```